# How do you record and track your business logic for software projects?

Tags: business-logic, business, business-rules, logic

In my work, which is a UK university, we currently have no specific way of recording and tracking business logic and rules as they arise from stakeholders for our in-house software projects.

We use Agile Scrum and put things into the usual product backlog items, etc. but the logic is often clouded in multiple different items and its clarity is then lost. This then causes confusion later and the stakeholders sometimes say "we didn't ask for that" when they did, and vice versa.

I am fairly new to the team and a junior developer so not involved in the BA side but want to prevent us getting stung again in future.

Is there a good way or single repository or even dedicated piece of software that handles this?

Any thought would be greatly appreciated.

PS We currently use Azure DevOps as our main software for managing projects. Thanks

Comment: Are the issues simply about requirements not being clear? Eg. one guy telling you that is not what he asked for. Or is it about different groups of stakeholders giving you conflicting requirements? Eg. You implement one guy's request, only for second guy to come and request you change it, frustrating the first requestor?

Answer (score 3):

> We use Agile Scrum and put things into the usual product backlog items, etc. but the logic is often clouded in multiple different items and its clarity is then lost. This then causes confusion later and the stakeholders sometimes say "we didn't ask for that" when they did, and vice versa.

If you’re doing scrum, every task falls under a story and every story is reviewed by a stakeholder and has an acceptance test. If not then the product owner isn’t doing their job. This is why they review the backlog.

“We didn’t ask for this” should only come up when you can say “you asked for that. That’s why you get this”

Demos do show people surprises. Scrum already has all the tools to trace work back to how it got requested. But nothing will ever ensure there are never any surprises. Sometimes people just won’t see how asking for X requires Y until you show them Y. At which point they finally tell you about Z.

Which is exactly why we demo early and often.

Comment: Ah yes, you remind me - our management have let the product owners go so we're just a team of Devs trying to do everything (badly at present). Maybe therein lies the answer. Actual staff to do these jobs.

Comment: So many teams forget that agile is not a dev team thing, it's a company philosophy thing.

Comment: @StephenBeale if you guys do the job you won’t need the extra body. Get in the habit of asking what work traces back to until people get the hint.

Answer (score 2):

I think Azure Dev Ops (old name: Team Foundation) does handle this as long as you are using the tasks/bugs/epics etc

If A feature is requested, Make a Task/Story/Epic for that feature with detailed note from the meeting etc. Then link your PRs to that task.

If any questions come up about a section of code you should be able to work out which PR added that section and work your way back to the original Task with all the notes ie. "requested by X for reason Y"

Generally though, you want to try and avoid this confusion. Keep the request and the delivery close together if possible and if not remind people: "This sprint we are aiming to deliver feature X, which Y requested and will solve Q. This has the side effect of Z which has been signed off as acceptable"

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, we are doing this in effect but I was wondering if there was a way to view the logic at a high-level outside of these tasks/bugs/epics etc as they become very granular with a focus on code and, I feel, lose sight of the bigger picture. Cheers.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I mean if you dont write things down, you don't write them down. my advice is to write them down. My additional advice is to remind people what they asked for before you give them it. You could also try shorter sprints

Comment: also maybe do you use "sprint goals"?

Comment: we do use goals, yes. I suppose I am thinking along the lines of Gherkin/Cucumber but not expressly for testing. Thanks again.

Comment: If looking at a new area of the code, how do you get a picture of all the Zs that have been signed off on? Do you expect people to track down and read potentially hundreds of tickets?

Comment: that sounds like a different problem from the one described tbh. I wouldn't recommend keeping extensive documentation just to answer people who are forgetting what they asked for. Presumably there are tests or documentation that show/describe correct functionality to whatever the required standard is

Comment: I would add that presumption to your answer, as the absence of said documentation is not unusual and contributes to this situation. And tests don't describe why behaviour is required.

Answer (score 1):

> "We didn't ask for that"

As SM, these claims would raise a red flag for me. Something is going wrong with the communication and/or the Scrum implementation. They could be a good reason to start doing retrospectives at the end of **every** sprint and discuss these matters.

If you are doing professional Scrum, events should give you enough opportunities to perform control checks along the sprints.

If you aren't doing professional Scrum, it's an opportunity to learn about the framework, the SM role and bring these issues to the table yourself and get the whole team involved because the solution cannot depend on a single person.

Back to the core question, you could add a CHANGELOG.md file to the source code. Something along the lines of [this](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.1.0/)<sup>1</sup>, but enriched with issues' ID, sprint goals and number, etc.

The alternative is placing this information as SCM comments. Some SCMs allow links to issue trackers (Jira, Redmine, Asana, etc.). However, I don't think SCMs can give you the best support to format and search the information as you need it.

The advantage of the changelog file over comments is, essentially, the format. It's plain text. You can format it and arrange the info as deemed best. SCM's text searches will complement the results (files with code) with literature (changelog's entries).

Also is a single "file-to-go" vs "go the issue tracker, then the SCM and then the source code".

---

*Side note: This Changelog file is not supposed to be public as those we see in public SCMs or Official websites. Not even for stakeholders. The only audience of the file is the Scrum team. More specifically, for developers.*

<sup>1:Only for illustration or guidance. Adapt the format, the content and the literature to the needs of the team.</sup>

Comment: If you use a changelog/issue tracker, how do you maintain a big picture view of the _current requirements_, once the number of issues hits the thousands or tens of thousands? Do you expect everyone to read the hundreds of prior issues that are relevant to any single area of functionality, and somehow discern which are still relevant and how they interact?

Comment: The changelog doesn't track every single commit or little change of the code, only the relevant ones to allow you to "draw" a timeline for epics or stories and see their evolution over time. Changelogs usually put the recent changes on the top, so the most recent info and state of the source are at the beginning of the file. The big picture of a feature must be gathered by searching through the file as you would for through the issue tracker. The main difference is that you are doing it in a SCM which allows you to inspect the code in a retrospective manner while consulting the changelog.

Comment: The overall picture you want to see at a single glance is complicated at the scale of thousands of issues. It will take an effort from you all to keep the traceability and documentation up to date. Either you draw it (diagrams) or you write it (changelogs, issue trackers, reports, etc) it's additional work. The length of this info and how accurate and up to date should be, depends on what you need it for. For example, my changelogs help me to know what has been added, removed or deleted to the big picture. The whys are links to the issue tracker.

Comment: As for the linked example for the changelog. Take it as a reference, if you find a format that works for you, then go ahead. For example, you could sort the entries by features, or epics and for each one, apply the suggested notation `added`, `deleted`, `fixed`, etc...

Comment: Yes its additional work. The question is whether a changelog is the best way of applying that additional work, given its still not a perticuarly usable format to read through, and its not clear what it adds over commit messages and tickets? At least with commit messages in the SCM, you also get tooling that lets you quickly identify changes associated with specific files.

Comment: The problem with using commit messages or tag descriptions is that not everyone is so methodic. It takes a while to educate everyone on writing good comments to allow the kind of tracking you want. On a daily basis, I do a lot of commits and I have a hard time correlating them all into a single commit at the end. Now imagine you have a team of 5 or more members each of which also has a branch. When everything is merged into develop or main, having a nice "literature" of what's in and out of a feature is not that simple.

Comment: The changelog gives you structure and guidance others can adopt and follow. It's agnostic to the timelines of the commits. You can write it in the order you want. Links to commits, blame, tags, issue trackers, etc are only for enrichment. You can rearrange the content without messing with other tools and data sources. Given they are plain text, the content is searchable by the SCM text search.

Comment: What stops people being as messy in a changelog? Or if you have 20 people all working on parallel branch per feature. How do you merge the changelog?

Comment: I doubt you have 20 ppl working on the same feature. Even then, you only need to edit the file once. Say, at the end of the sprint. This can be done by a single person and the person can be elected in the daily meeting. If your team have no organization at all, well, that's a different problem, but even then, it only takes adding a mark to the file to reserve 1,2,3 line "#Reserved", Even if still causes some conflicts... well, it's solving conflicts between "#reserved" and a short, nice, concise comments. I'm sure you can deal with that in less than a minute.

Comment: The file doesn't introduce any complexity. You can keep looking, but you will find that the solution boils down to a team committed to maintaining a single file. The hardest part is precisely achieving this commitment. The team has to find value in that (or the final solution they find), or nothing will work. If the "big picture" only matters to the OP, I'm afraid he's alone in this dutty,

Comment: How long is such a change log in practice? My experience has been that such high level descriptions of the features of the current state of a complex system, without any context, typically run to a couple of thousand lines of prose at least. If I took all the current system I working on, with a one line description per ticket implemented, would result in a 5000 line file. With a valuable description, somewhere in the order of 10 to 20 thousand lines. How do you navigate such a file to know what parts of it you need to know about?

Comment: An alternative is the team commits to maintaining the current state and reasoning organized across multiple files (like we organize our code) in a system that actually supports organization, diagrams, and full text search with stemming. Getting the team to commit to any documentation other than the issue tracker is a different problem though.